# How to read bytes from a file, whereas the result byte[] is exactly as long

Tags: java, file-io

I want the result `byte[]` to be exactly as long as the file content. How to achieve that.

I am thinking of `ArrayList<Byte>`, but it doe not seem to be efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd go [the Guava route](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toByteArray%28java.io.File%29):

```
File f = ...
byte[] content = Files.toByteArray(f);
```

Apache Commons IO has similar utility methods if you want.

If that's not what you want, it's not too hard to write that code yourself:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(File f) throws IOException {
    if (f.length() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(f + " is too large!");
    }
    int length = (int) f.length();
    byte[] content = new byte[length];
    int off = 0;
    int read = 0;
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
    try {
        while (read != -1 && off < length) {
            read = in.read(content, off, (length - off));
            off += read;
        }
        if (off != length) {
            // file size has shrunken since check, handle appropriately
        } else if (in.read() != -1) {
            // file size has grown since check, handle appropriately
        }
        return content;
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: An additional question: as we know the `length()` already, why not just use `in.read(content)` (notation is from your solution)? (It works well on my computer.)

Comment: @Dante: because `read()` doesn't necessarily fill the entire array, even if the file is big enough. It *could* only read parts of it. I suspect this only to happen with bigger files (or maybe even only with non-file bases `InputStream` objects).

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure [File#length()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) doesn't iterate through the file. (*Assuming this is what you meant by `length()`*) Each OS provides efficient enough mechanisms to find file size without reading it all.

Comment: `File.length()` **definitely** doesn't need to read the file on any sane file system. Some ancient file systems had to iterate over each block of the file to get the file size, but that time is long gone.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate an adequate buffer (if necessary, resize it while reading) and keep track of how many bytes read. After finishing reading, create a new array with the exact length and copy the content of the reading buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Small function that you can use :

```
// Returns the contents of the file in a byte array.
public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Get the size of the file
    long length = file.length();

    // You cannot create an array using a long type.
    // It needs to be an int type.
    // Before converting to an int type, check
    // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException(file.getName() + " is too large");
    }

    // Create the byte array to hold the data
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

    // Read in the bytes
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length
           && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
    }

    // Close the input stream and return bytes
    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Note that you leave the `FileInputStream` open when anything goes wrong (`IOException` during read or the last check fails). That should be avoided by using `try`-`finally`.